# Fastest method of computing every possible combination of four array choices?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I am working with four MATLAB arrays of size 169x14, 207x14, 94x14, and 108x14. I would like to produce a single array which has the linear addition of every possible row combination of the four arrays. For example, one such combination may be the 99th row of array1, the 72nd row of array2, 6th row of array3, and 27th row of array 4 added together as a single row. These arrays are named helm, chest, arm, leg - this is for a stat calculator of a video game.

My first attempt at this was the following:

```
for i = 1:length(lin_helm)
    for k = 1:length(lin_arm)
        for j = 1:length(lin_leg)
            for g = 1:length(lin_leg)
               armor_comb = [armor_comb;
                   i j k g helm_array(i,2:15)+chest_array(j,2:15)+arm_array(k,2:15)+leg_array(g,2:15)];
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Which uses nested for loops for each array and simply adds the rows together (note that 'lin_X' are just numbered vectors for the row number and the rows of the array are 2:15 because the first column is a row iterator). The first four columns of this result array can be ignored, they are just denoting which rows were selected from the other arrays. To say the least, this is **extremely** slow.

I then tried omitting the last for loop to instead take the first three selections and add them as an entire matrix to the entire last array. This was done by taking the addition of the first three row selections and using a matrix of ones. I chose to do this for the largest array, chest, to save the most time.

```
for i = 1:length(lin_helm)
    for k = 1:length(lin_arm)
        for j = 1:length(lin_leg)
            armor_comb = [armor_comb;
                    i*ones(length(lin_chest),1) j*ones(length(lin_chest),1) k*ones(length(lin_chest),1) lin_chest' ones(length(lin_chest),14).*[helm_array(i,2:15)+leg_array(j,2:15)+arm_array(k,2:15)]+chest_array(:,2:15)];
        end
    end
end
```

This was significantly faster, but still extremely slow compared to the total array size needed.

I am not sure how to make this process faster by using matrix math. To generalize my issue, I am trying to find the numerical array of all possible row additions of an AxN, BxN, CxN, and DxN where any given selection takes one row from each array with no repeats.

All online documentation I can find just says to use nested for loops because they assume your array sizes are small. This is unpractical for my application, so I am seeking help on how to use matrices (or another method) to speed up computation time.

Comment: You're trying to make a matrix which has 355 million rows and 14 columns; at 8 bytes per double that's nearly 40GB just to store some armour stats? Sounds like a problem which would be well served by you taking a step back and seeing if there's a way to achieve what you want without generating all possibilities. Loops are not inherently slow in MATLAB, but dynamically growing a 40GB array will be, at least pre-allocate `armor_comb = zeros(169*207*94*108,14)` before the loops and then populate each row rather than appending it in your loop

Comment: In computing, very pre-calculating things and storing them can be an option, but often is not. Most videogames have a function/equation that will output the strength of the armour given a level, and thus they never need to store a big array. If each of those  arrays were functions instead, you could just evaluate them once and it would take negligible time.

Answer (score 0):

For making indexes (the first columns of your final matrix), you can try something like this:

```matlab
function i=indexes(i1, i2)
  i=[kron(i1, ones(size(i2, 1), 1)) kron(ones(size(i1, 1), 1), i2)];
end
```

If `a` and `b` are column vectors of indexes 1, 2, ..., then `indexes(a, b)` will be the pairs of index combos, and you can repeat for additional indexing columns, e.g., `indexes(indexes(a, b), c)`.

If you have the indexes, say `ii`, you can add up what you want with something like

```matlab
array1(ii(:, 1), 2:15) + array2(ii(:, 2), 2:15)
```

Prepend with `ii` if you really need to.

This will be much faster than a naive loop like you have initially.  E.g., on my somewhat old Matlab, this:

```matlab
n=10;
a=(1:2*n)';
b=(1:3*n)';
c=(1:5*n)';
tic
ii=indexes(indexes(a,b),c);
toc
tic
jj=[];
k=1;
for i1=1:length(a)
  for i2=1:length(b)
    for i3=1:length(c)
      jj(k, :)=[i1 i2 i3];
      k=k+1;
    end
  end
end
toc
```

gives

```matlab
Elapsed time is 0.003514 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.754066 seconds.
```

If you pre-allocate the storage for the loop case like `jj=zeros(size(ii));`, that's also significantly faster, though still slower than the `kron`-based approach, like with `n=100`:

```matlab
Elapsed time is 3.323197 seconds.
Elapsed time is 9.825276 seconds.
```